# How to do Planner/ business Calendar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, calendar

I am planning to do calendar which contain dynamic event below date. But i am not getting good sample regarding it.
What is exact name call as per image below in android or share some idea. I got many apk and image related to it.
but no exact idea behind  it, does android support it. I plan is to show calendar in Month, week, day wise.
After searching lot in google I am writing this. 
Does it supports all version from 2.3 to 4. i have seen some blog business calendar supports on above verison 4.
Thanks a lot for kind and great ideas.

[image]

Comment: @Lefteris any idea how to do it

Comment: I guess u need Google Calender